# C# game using only Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to develop a Board Game . Can i create it using only Windows Form Application? I don't Want to use XNA . If it is possible to create with windows form application , how can i convert it into an executable file . I don't want to run it as a console application . I want to create it as a Game .

```
/*
It is a board game.
        15   14    13    12     11    10    9
        16   28    29    30     31    32    8
        17   27    42    43     44    33    7
        18   26    41    48     45    34    6  
        19   25    40    47     46    35    5
        20   24    39    38     37    36    4
        21   22    23     0      1     2    3

 It is my board structure . Player one starts at square 0 . If he puts one , he will   
 get into the game . Then he can move his coin up to 23.He can get into 24 , if he 
 already cut the other player coins . Cut in the sense , player 0 places his coin on a 
 square that contains another player coins.Then he can move his coin from 24 to 48 .    
 when the coin reaches 48 , it will be completed . If player 0 completes his 6 coins 
 first , he will be the winner .   
*/
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    public static int playerCount;
    public static int totalSquares = 49;
    public static int totalCoins = 6;
    public static bool errorFlag = false;
    public static bool flagrepeat = false;
    public static bool winner=false;

    static void Main()
    {
        if (ErrorTypes.errors==null)
        {
            ErrorTypes.addMessage();
        }
        getPlayers(); // To get the number of players

        startGame();// It will get the name of the player and 
        // will thorw exception if anything goes wrong and will
        // call the main function again.

    }  
/*
* If a coin reaches center square , then it completes
* A player wins if he completes all the six coins
*/
    public static void setWinner(player[] obj) 
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < Program.playerCount; k++)
        {
            if (obj[k].completedcoins == 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Winner is player " + (k + 1));
                winner = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void play(player[] obj)
    {
        bool rollrepeat; // If a player puts one or five or six , he will get another          chance.
        board boards = new board(); // It contains 49 squares
        List<int> rollstore = new List<int>(10); // To store the rolls of a single  player. 
    // Eg is [6,5,6,2] . Coz no repeat for 2. so his turn ends . Now he has to move the   coin by selecting coin and //rollindex.
        List<int> temprollstore = new List<int>(10);
        int roll;
        bool final = false;
        int i = 0;
        Random rn = new Random(); // To generate roll
        bool flag = false, tempflag = false;

        int[] pos;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!gameover())
            {
                setWinner(obj);
                if (final == false)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    while (i < Program.playerCount)
                    {
    /*
    * to reset the flags so that another player can use it
    */
                        if (flag == true || flagrepeat == true)
                        {
                            flagrepeat = false;
                            flag = false;
                        }
    /*
    * 
    */
                        while (true)
                        {                  
            // This part of the does the job of storing the rolls and call the move   function
    // when the roll ends
          }        
                    }
                    print(obj);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress a Key To Go Next Round ");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please Suggest me a way to create the board and place the coins on the square.

Comment: You can create a `Windows Form Application`. it's content is up to you. this will create an `exe` file which you can use to launch you application

Comment: @Omribitan I don't want to execute it via Microsoft Visual Studio(F5).Rather than i want to double click a file and it should run as a game . Sorry if my question is silly . I couldn't understand.

Comment: By default, When you compile a windows forms application from visual studio it's create the `.exe` file in the [Solution folder]\bin\debug or release depending on your build configuration. you can access this folder and run the `.exe` with a double click ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Windows Form Application` by selecting

> File-New Project-Visual C# or Visual Basic - Windows Forms Application

There you can develop your game as you would like.

By default, visual studio creates your project's output files in the `[Project's path]\Bin\Debug` or  `[Project's path]\Bin\Release` depending on the build configuration you complied in. This can be changed from the project's properties.

In those folders, lies the `.exe` file along with other files, resources or dll it needs to execute correctly.

From there you can run your `.exe` with double click no need for visual studio.

you can learn more about visual studio output files from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235517.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: I have one more doubt . My game contains 49 squares[7 by 7 matrix].It is a multiplayer game[2 to 4 players]. Six coins for each player.It's a dice game . When a player gets one , he can enter into the game.Please suggest a way to place a coin on the initial square and move the coin from the current square to the new square based on the rolls. I have written the code with C# successfully . It works . But I have problem in the GUI implementation. Please Help me.

Comment: @GopiNath if my answer, answered your first question, please mark at is accepted. as to your second question, open a new thread (question) and post the code that you already implemnted. try to focus the problem as much as you can, and me and the other awesome developers at Stackoverflow will try to help. good luck :)

Comment: I tried to Vote up . But i couldn't do that . Because My reputations are zero. Sorry for this.I will post my code and help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just select File-New Project-Visual C# or Visual Basic-Forms Application.

then when you finished coding, just compile as release (select release on top bar of visual studio, its debug as default and compile) and your .exe file will be inside of your (project folder)/bin/release.

Take this file and you dont need visual studio to run now on.

Comment: Thanks Emre Acar and Omribitan.